# помогите выяснить причину

Tags: windows

почему ноутбук с процессором core tm2 1.8 ghz озу 2гб жесткий диск 80 гб(НЕ ЛАГАЕТ)

ПК с процессором pentium4 3.0 ghz озу 3.5гб жесткий диск 160 гб (ЛАГАЕТ,отказывается запускать любую игру) видеокарты в обоих случаях нет
ноут с 7  32р винндой   пк с10 64р виндой помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш ответ содержится в Вашем же вопросе. Pentium4 является 32х разрядным одноядерным процессором, а процессор технологии Сore tm2 (DUO) уже имеет 64х разрядность и два ядра.

Более детально о процессорах можно прочитать в Вики, или ознакомиться на оффициальном сайте производителя Intel (en).